# Does Alfresco support adding constraint to associations?

Tags: java, alfresco

Every example that I find in internet is about adding constraints to properties. So does Alfresco support adding constraint to associations or not?

Comment: What kind of contraint do you think about?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what exactly you are after, but you can add custom behavior to association lifecycle events. Hence, you are free to validate and blow up in case you don't like something about a specific association - or lack thereof.

You may want to check the Association Policies at http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/AlfrescoOne/5.0/PublicAPI/org/alfresco/repo/node/NodeServicePolicies.html

An exhaustive example is at https://www.alfresco.com/blogs/lcabaceira/2015/04/07/alfresco-behaviours-and-policies/

Answer (score 1):

You can constrain the type of object that is on the source side of an association and you can constrain the type of the object that is on the target side of an association.

The example below shows the target being constrained to instances of sc:doc:

```
<association name="sc:relatedDocuments">
    <title>Related Documents</title>
    <source>
        <mandatory>false</mandatory>
        <many>true</many>
    </source>
    <target>
        <class>sc:doc</class>
        <mandatory>false</mandatory>
        <many>true</many>
    </target>
</association>
```

Unlike some other systems, Alfresco associations are not first-class objects and do not have properties, so beyond the type of object on either end, whether or not it is required, and the cardinality, there is nothing else that could be constrained.